# How to map two entities through an associate link entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I need to keep record of various businesses their cities and their branches in each city. Each business might be in different cities and in each city might have different branches.

*Take a bank as an example*. It might be in cities A and B and in city A might have two branches and in city B only one.

I suppose the branch table should have branchid and foreign keys of both primary keys of the join table. In this way I can make sure no branch will be associate to more than one combination of city and business.

```
 Business       City
     \          /
  BusinessID CityID    <<join table has primary keys of Business and City tables
          |
        Branch
BranchID BusinessID CityID
```

**Sample data**

```
Business Table          
1         
2       
3        

City Table
A
B
C

Join Table
Business_City
1         A
1         B
2         A
3         C

Branch Table
Business City   Branch
1          A      I1
1          A      I2
1          B      I6
2          A      I5
3          C      I3
```

As you can see businesses 1 and 2 are both in city A. Business 1 has two branches in city A whereas business 2 has just one branch etc.

How should I map the Branch to a Business and a City?

Comment: Shouldn't the institution and course be linked?

Comment: @MadProgrammer no there are some other constraints that make it like this.  Also, institution is the place that the course will be held and each combination of course and student can have many institutions.

Comment: Are you sure you need a join table of Business_city ?. You can get the same data from Branch Table.. No need for business_city table..

Comment: @user1354678 I need that imagine I just need to know which businesses are in NYC only.

Comment: That's why I'm saying only Branch table is needed coz you can get the same information from branch table. For this kind of condition - `need to know which businesses are in NYC only` , you can use this query `select business from branchTable where city='?' group by business`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your mappings should look like:

```
@Entity
public class Business {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "business")
    private Set<Branch> branches = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class City {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city")
    private Set<Branch> branches = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Branch {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "business_id")
    private Business business;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;
}
```

This intermediate Entity mapping is [better than using a @ManyToMany](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) association which might generate some less efficient SQL queries and would not allow you to add some additional columns to the link table.

Comment: thanks for your answer, does that mean each city can have just one business?

Comment: No, as explained in the sample data business 1 and 2 are both in city A. Each business can be in multiple cities, and can have multiple branches in each city. Each city can have multiple businesses in it and can have multiple branches of each business.

Comment: Ok. I removed the constraints. Now it allows you to have as many business and branches you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, I need to wait for 20 hours before awarding the bounty.